# For loop (Javascript) filling empty divs with 1-28

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
         <html>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="hidden"></div>                    (pay no attention to hidden divs)
    <div class="hidden"></div>                    (pay no attention to hidden divs)
    <div class="hidden"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div> 
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
             </html>

               <css>
               .hidden{
               visibility:hidden; 
               width:110px;
               float:left;
               border:1px solid red;
               height:100px;
              text-align:right;
              vertical-align:top;
              font-size:30px;
              overflow:hidden;
              }
            .box{
    margin:5px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-size:30px;
    }
            </css>
```

what javascript loop can i write in order to fill the box div's in order to
for loop through all 28 box's. 
This is for a calendar if that helps describe what i am trying to generate with
the for loop I have tried to understand but cannot comprehend the function
needed.Is this so basic that i need to review javascript all over again? 
Help is appreciated thank you very much beforehand.
just showing html and css layout and selectors in order for you to
understand please feel free to ask for more content in order 
to help if this is not enough to go off of.

Comment: You should show the JS that you've already tried.

Comment: use `getElementsByClassName` and then loop through the resulting collection setting the content.

Comment: Keep in mind that `getElementsByClassName` isn't supported in IE8 or below.

Comment: Only show relevant code. If we should pay no attention to 'hidden' div's, don't include it in your post.

Comment: "Is this so basic that i need to review javascript all over again?" - Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.box').each(function(i) {
        $(this).text(i+1);
    });
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/magnafides/skFQS/2/

Comment: OP isn't using jQuery.

Comment: this works but generates a zero which i do not want only 1-28

Comment: @user3335424: So...`i+1`. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid adding the boxes to the HTML at all and use JavaScript to add them to the page by adding the box HTML to an array and joining that to the wrapper:

```
var el = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var html = [];
for (var i = 1, l = 28; i <= l; i++) {
  html.push('<div class="box">' + i + '</div>');
}
el.innerHTML = html.join('');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/9C9Rz/)

Comment: That would probably be a better solution. Since the OP said this was for a calendar and, of course, not all months have 28 days.

Comment: Looking at the fiddle, it seems to be working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
for (var i=0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    divs[i].innerHTML = i+1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RzqL3/1/

If there are other non-div elements with the class `box` then you'd need to check the `nodeName` to filter them out.